# It's not you, it's us We couldn't complete your request right now. Please try again later- awsapps login

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, request, signature, expired-sessions

awsapps login page shows -It's not you, it's us We couldn't complete your request right now. Please try again later
or

access key and secret could not connect aws account with an error message as
"An error occurred (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the DescribeCluster operation: Signature expired: 20220801T134645Z is now earlier than 20220801T143813Z (20220801T144313Z - 5 min.)"

Answer (score 9):

Both the errors are due to date and time mismatch, ie.. try syncing system time settings to your exact location and login,that worked for me.